# SAPUI5 - Entity with sub Entity

Tags: javascript, json, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm really new at the SAPUI5 world. I'm trying to create a FIORI-App but I'm stucking at the right way to bind my data.

I'm creating a SplitApp. In the master view, u've got a list of trainings from which u can choose to display the details.
Now I want to display a list of description of the training in the detailpage.
My JSON model looks like this:

```
[{
    "Objid": "50000001",
    "Name": "Word für Anfänger",
    "Description" : [{
        "Title" : "Trainingsinhalt",
        "Content" : "Dies ist ein Trainingsinhalt"
     }, {
        "Title" : "Hinweise",
        "Content" : "Meine Hinweise"
     }]
}, {
    "Objid": "50000002",
    "Name": "Excel für Anfänger",
    "Description" : [{
        "Title" : "Trainingsinhalt",
        "Content" : "Dies ist ein Trainingsinhalt"
    }, {
        "Title" : "Hinweise",
        "Content" : "Meine Hinweise"
    }]
}]
```

I'm not sure if it is the right way to create an entity below an entity.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The data structure seem reasonable to me. If you have any concrete problems, please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure works well.
In case you are stuck:

Load your data into a named JSON model (e.g. "training")

```
var trainingModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(yourData);
oView.setModel(trainingModel , "training");
```

Bind your list in your master view to the relevant field (e.g. Name).

```
<items>
   <ObjectListItem
         type="{device>/listItemType}"
         press="onPress"
         title="{training>Name}"
         number=""
         numberUnit="">
   </ObjectListItem>
</items>
```

On navigation to your Detail view get the id of the Name selected in your detail controller.

```
onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
       var oParameters1 = oEvent.getParameters();
       var sId1 = oParameters1.arguments.detailId;
```

bind your detail view to this element of your data:

```
    var sPath = "training>/" + sId1 + "/";
    this.getView().bindElement(sPath);
```

And then finish off by binding your (as an example) table fields to the two child fields of description.

```
<Table id="idProductsTable"
       inset="false"
       items="{
       path: 'training>Description'
       }">
    <columns>
        <Column mergeDuplicates="true"
                width="40%">
            <Text text="Title" />
        </Column>
        <Column mergeDuplicates="true"
                width="40%">
            <Text text="Content" />
        </Column>
      </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text
                        text="{training>Title}" />
                <Text
                        text="{training>Content}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

And that does it - your data in its current form is highly usable.